# Jmeter tool create request..cannot handle array parameters and dynamically created parameters

Tags: arrays, json, api, jmeter, createfile

I'm having 2 issues when trying to do the create api requests using the jmeter tool

1). How to handle an array parameter. "Versions": "$[Versions]"

getting the following error message

> {"timestamp":"2020-02-14T07:18:33.720+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad
>   Request","message":"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of
>   `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>` out of VALUE_STRING token;
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>` out of
>   VALUE_STRING token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 15,
>   column: 22]

2). how to handle dynamically created time stamp parameter **createtime**: `"${createtime}"`

getting the following error message

> {"timestamp":"2020-02-14T07:17:58.942+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad
>   Request","message":"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type
>   `java.time.OffsetDateTime` from String \"${factoryCompleteTime}\":
>   Failed to deserialize java.time.OffsetDateTime:
>   (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text
>   '${factoryCompleteTime}' could not be parsed at index 0; nested
>   exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot
>   deserialize value of type `java.time.OffsetDateTime` from String
>   \"${factoryCompleteTime}\": Failed to deserialize
>   java.time.OffsetDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException)
>   Text '${factoryCompleteTime}' could not be parsed at index 0\n at
>   [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 15, column: 24]

My json body looks like this.

```
"Versions": "$[Versions]",
"createtime": "${createtime}"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you should pass this `Versions` a little bit differently, for example if it should be a [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) it should look like:

   ```
   "Versions": [${Versions}],
   ```

   or

   ```
   "Versions": ${Versions},
   ```
2. It appears that your `${factoryCompleteTime}` variable doesn't have a value so it has been replaced by the default placeholder. Use [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) combination in order to check the variable value, it should be in format of the [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) to wit something like: `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00`